# How to read a file in python and ignore the comment part to save values to variables?

Tags: python

I have this file

```
-200   200  # Domain size in X direction in meter
-200   200  # Domain size in Y direction in meter
 0.0   200.0    # Domain size in Z direction in meter
25      25      25       # Number of nodes in X, Y and Z direction
1          # Number of measurments  
-0.0  0.0    5.0
3.44e-12
```

I want to read this using python and save only the values to certain variables. I tried

```
with open("input.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.partition('#')[0]
        line = line.rstrip()
        fields = line.strip().split()
        print(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2])
```

to separate them into fields but it didn't work and returns empty fields with error

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If I try to access the 'fields'

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Your code works correctly for me. Are you sure that the error occurs here in the code you show?

Comment: i am trying to print the field and getting this error `
  File "D:/Simple/perm_field.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(fields[1])

IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Empty fields will be returned if you accidentally include empty line into file

Comment: You didn't include that bit of code.  But the problem then is that you have some line that after splitting only has one value, and you're trying to reference the second one.  That line with the 3.44e-12 looks like a culprit.   Don't refer to an index higher than length(fields)

Comment: Last line in your input file contains only one value - so fields[0] = 3.44e-12 and fields[1] will throw IndexError

Comment: I removed empty lines, it still gives same error

Comment: Is it possible to save the values with any other way

Comment: Please show the code that is actually producing the error. There is no print statement in the code that you have shown, so we can't tell what you're trying to print.

Comment: I updated the question details

Answer (score 0):

To avoid getting `IndexError` while accessing `fields[1]` or `fields[2]`, you could set up a condition that checks if they exist. If not, then input a default value to print (say 0).

```
if len(fields) == 0:
    print ("0","0","0")
elif len(fields) == 1:
    print (fields[0], "0", "0")
elif len(fields) == 2:
    print (fields[0], fields[1], "0")
else:
    print (fields[0], fields[1], fields[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the **print** statement of your code with the below two statements:

```
for val in fields:
    print (val, end=' ')
```

Problem is that in some lines you have less than three values. So, fields[2] will generate an index error.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that you are trying to print (or save to a variable) three fields when some of your rows only have one field.

Based on the comments inside your data block, it sounds like each line of data within a block of data is not supposed to be interpreted the same way. If this is the case, you should really be parsing each line differently rather than trying to use the same code to parse every line.